# how to mask the load of open back trucks using Mask R-CNN and background subtraction?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

i need to detect and segment the load of open back trucks in the roads. how can i mask and extract the load area using background subtraction and Mask R-CNN ?

as a simple example, i download a background image and Photoshop the truck and the load into that.

background: https://i.ibb.co/DpSWc84/Original.jpg

modified: https://i.ibb.co/6NVsYGq/Modified.jpg

i used BS and Mask R-CNN but the output is not fit enough. output mask includes trucks border area and also some holes and noises in load section.

```py
def applyMask(image, maskList): # apply masks that created by Mask R-CNN to image
    masked_for_load = resize(image,maskList[0].shape)
    for mask in maskList :
        masked_for_load[:, :] = np.where(mask == 1,0,masked_for_load[:, :]) # set pixels that include cars or trucks to zero
    return masked_for_load

(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

# threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# output mask, ready to apply on original image
loadMask = applyMask(thresh,maskList)
```

Mask R-CNN output: https://i.ibb.co/jgxr65Z/bar-out.jpg

BS output: https://i.ibb.co/yQZT0V4/before-mask.jpg

after subtracting R-CNN output from BS output:  https://i.ibb.co/JqZwfvg/after-mask.jpg

but the expected output must be like this: https://i.ibb.co/z40fqjq/expected.jpg

how can i achieve this using python, opencv and keras tools?

Comment: Since you already the the contour of the object, you can create a black mask then draw the contour onto the mask with `cv2.drawContours()`

Comment: @nathancy i have contour of the 'car' but i need to the contour of the 'load' on the truck. a black mask is used to delete the car area from the finally mask but some unwanted border still exist there. i don't know how can i delete these unwanted sections and extract fit  contour of the 'load' .